# Javascript snippet in dev tools seems to not execute after a web page changes url

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-devtools, devtools, browser-automation

I'm very new to JavaScript and trying to automate a small test process in a browser (Sources - Snippets) with JavaScript, and it spans over several web pages, and I noticed that after a page reloads or a new page loads the subsequent code seems to not execute. Even if I set a big timeout. The code lines executed separately in the "console" tab of the dev tools work fine. So the question is: what shall I do to make them execute one after another in one snippet?

Here is just one step after which nothing seems to happen:

```js
(function() {
  //Link   
  document.querySelector("#main-content > p:nth-child(6) > a").click(); // a click works, but the next line does not do anything even with a big timeout.

  //LOGIN FORM
  //User name
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector("form input[formcontrolname='benutzername']").value = 'xxxx'
  }, 3000); //when executed separately in the console, it works.
})()
```

Comment: tried it and your code works, see link here, make sure you are not missing anything in your attribute name - https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-zhukovsky-q86ex?file=/src/index.js:73-95

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the 2nd line of code works, if executed separately on a loaded page. But if I execute it together with the 1st line of code (after which a web page changes), there seems to happen nothing after the 1st line of code executes. So I'm wondering if I have to wait for a specific event like "page loaded".

Comment: This behavior is on any web page I noticed. Here for example:
https://www.patreon.com

I made a similar code, and the 2nd line does not execute after the 1st one. But executes without the 1st one

document.querySelector("a[href='/login']").click()
setTimeout(()=> {
    document.querySelector("#email").value='test'
    }, 5000)  

I tried to send "DOMContentLoaded" event, but it did not work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from an expert:
*"When automating from the console, the code won't survive a page reload because the code is running in the document process, so when it changes the code is gone."*